# Unary Operations fused with assignment

Tags: java, assignment-operator, unary-operator, binary-operators

Doubtful result in the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
int i = 2;
i = i+=2 + i++;
System.out.println(i); }
```

Was expecting **8** as output, as 'i+=2' should *update* i, but its not behaving so.

> Output: 6

I infer that the short-hand assignment operator is returning **4** as expected but not updating the same in variable i. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: This is undefined behavior in C/C++. For a good reason. You shouldn't do it anywhere.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure, but in Java it *is* defined, and while you shouldn't do it in practice it's an interesting academic question.

Comment: @berry120:Thanks for the well versed explanation Sir Berry. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i++` is a postfix increment - it increments i, then essentially returns the old value of i. The equivalent prefix operator, `++i`, would return the "updated" value, but that's not what's being used here.

`i+=2` works differently however, it's essentially equivalent to `i+2`, since it *does* return the updated value.

However, I think where the confusion arises is that you're looking at it like this:

```
i = (i += 2) + i++;
```

...which *does* give your expected result. `i+=2` gives 4, and updates `i` to 4, then `i++` returns 4 (instead of 5 since it's a post increment.) However, when you take operator precedence into the equation, Java actually "brackets" it like this by default:

```
i = i += (2 + i++);
```

*Just to clear up any confusion, Java evaluates it this way because the `+=` operator [has least precedence in this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), and therefore the addition expression (`+`) is calculated first.*

This bracketed statement is essentially equivalent to:

```
i = (i = i + (2 + i++));
```

Which in turn simplifies to:

```
i = i + (2 + i++);
```

So given the above statement, and evaluating from left to right, we first take the value of i (2), and then add to it the value of `2+i++`; the latter giving 4 (because of the postfix increment). So our final result is 2+4, which is 6.

Comment: And why is this returns 8: `i = 2; i = (i+=2) + i++;` ??

Comment: Ahh, you changed your answer..!! I was about to point this flaw.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Updated now to explain!

Comment: @Ravi Yup, I realised what I'd written wasn't quite right as soon as I wrote it..!

Comment: Subexpression are evaluated left to right, so the `i` to the left of `+=` is read before the increment. The increment actually does the last read of `i`. (Not that I can remember all the rules!)

Comment: @berry120:As java evaluates expressions from "right to left" then why does `++i+i++` returns `6`? As `i++` updates `i` at the end of the expression.
*Assuming `i` to be `2` by default*

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - I've updated the answer now to explain. Java doesn't evaluate from right to left given equal operator precedence, but in this case the `+` operation takes greater precedence so is evaluated first.

Comment: @berry120:Sir Berry, you made me create a new [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363112/ii-evaluation?answertab=active#tab-top) -_-