# ++i+i++ evaluation

Tags: java, unary-operator, expression-evaluation

> Confusion rose because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360084/unary-operations-fused-with-assignment?answertab=votes#tab-top). The author updated his post, and the result became clear.
>   **Conclusion: Java evaluates expressions from *left to right***

### Closed!

As evaluation of expression is done from *right to left* the following code should store `5` in `j`:

```
int i=2;
int j=++i+i++;
System.out.println(j);
```

But I get **6** as the output, which forces me to re-think the *right to left* evaluation idea. Kindly explain the theory here.

Comment: The theory is that anyone who writes an expression like that should be shot.  The above evidence, however, suggests that theory and practice differ.

Comment: @Hot Licks, we don't know that he won't be shot for it yet.

Comment: My eyes! Ze googles, zey do nothing!

Comment: While evaluation is in fact done left-to-right, your expression would also result in 6 when evaluated right-to-left!

Comment: 11 duplicate answers so far

Comment: @ValarDohaeris: Do explain Sir, how its **6** when evaluated from _right to left_
Am using JDK 1.7

Comment: Cf the answer of Tim Goodman.

Comment: @HotLicks:I would love to point a Gun to such coder, but I can't do that to my Interviewer. Sorry. ;)

Comment: Actually writing code like this: very, very bad.  Understanding the meaning of `++i`, `i++` and evaluation order well enough to be *able to* understand code like this: good.

Comment: @ValarDohaeris:Tim has explained the working of `i++ + ++i` and `++i+i++`. He has no where stated that the expr would result in _6_ if evaluated _R to L_

Comment: @TimGoodman: Agreed Sir Tim, but someone needs to explain this stuff to the _brainless_ interviewers! 
But I guess they promote learning of every _basic_ aspect of a language, and am striving for it. :)

Comment: @ChaZ, you understand that you have to evaluate both `++i` and the `i++` before summing them, right?  What @Valar is saying is that if you evaluate `i++` before `++i` it would change the value of those two expressions but the sum would still be the same (as illustrated in my answer where I actually rearranged the sum to force it to evaluate the terms in the opposite order.

Comment: Your "conclusion" seems a bit wrong, in other words.  The sum you get would be the same in a language that evaluates the right term of the sum first.

Comment: I feel like you're trying to read it as `((++i)+i)++` but that's not really right, `i++` is still evaluated before summing, it just uses the value that it got *before* incrementing (as if it's stored in a temp variable, like in my answer).  Applying ++ at the end of an expression like that wouldn't actually work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29386/discussion-between-chaz-and-tim-goodman)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 2;
int j = ++i + i++;
```

is the same as

```
int i = 2;

// This part is from ++i
i = i + 1;
int left = i; // 3

// This part is from i++
int right = i; // 3
i = i + 1;

int j = left + right; // 3 + 3 = 6
```

If instead you'd done:

```
int i = 2;
int j = i++ + ++i;
```

that would be equivalent to:

```
int i = 2;

// This part is from i++
int left = i; // 2
i = i + 1;

// This part is from ++i
i = i + 1;
int right = i; // 4


int j = left + right; // 2 + 4 = 6
```

So the sum is the same, but the terms being summed are different.

Answer (score 7):

You get 6 because it's `3 + 3`:

- the first OP is `++i` which increments *first* (to 3) then that value is used
- next OP is `+i` which adds 3 again
- last OP `++` doesn't take part in the addition, but it increments i after using it

Comment: I got the _right to left_ confusion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360084/unary-operations-fused-with-assignment?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption is false. Here's what [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) says :

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated
>   from left to right

So

```
++i+i++
```

is equivalent to

```
(++i)+(i++)
```

where `++i` is evaluated first.

This gives

```
3+3
```

which is **`6`** (and i has value `4` after this).

Answer (score 3):

The first `++` increments i.  The `+` adds i to itself.  i is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Where'd you get the idea that it is right-to-left? It is left-to-right.

[What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This how it works, since unary operators have more precedance than binary:

```
int i=2;
int j =(++i)+(i++);
        ^^^   ^^^ 
         3  +(i++) //The value of i is now 3.
        ^^^   ^^^
         3  +  3   //The value of i is incremented after it is assigned.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java and C#, the evaluation of subexpressions will be done left to right:

```
int j=++i + i++;
```

contains the following two subexpressions `++i` and `i++`. These subexpressions will be evaluated in this order so this will translate into:

```
int j= 3 + 3;
```

As in Java and C#, the `++i` will be executed returning `3` but i will be changed to `3` before the second `i++`. The second will return the current value of `i` which is `3` now and after `i++` the value of `i` will be `4`.

In C++ this would be undefined.

And in real-world, you do not want to type this code (except for code golfing)

Comment: ahhh... _left to right_ makes me feel soo good Sir Trin! As now am relaxed, and actually  I got the _right to left_ confusion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360084/unary-operations-fused-with-assignment?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Sebastien posted this link which seems very good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java

Comment: @ChaZ: left to right apply to subexpressions, if you were to write 2+4*2, 4*2 would be evaluated first, but if you write (a++) + (b++) * (c++), then (b++) would be evaluated, then (c++) then (b++) * (c++) ... etc

Comment: BlueTrin:Yes, because of _left to right_ precedence of `*` operator. The first evaluation of _(b++)_ is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating an expression such as `a+b`, before you can add 'b' to 'a', you need to know what 'a' is. In this case, a is ++i, which is 3, and b is i++ which is 3. Evaluating right-to-left gives 3 + 3 = 6